# Consistency of relational sentences.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $p$ and $q$ be binary relation constants, such that $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ exist for all $x, y$.

We consider three objects: $a, b, c$. Let $p(a, b)$ and $p(b, c)$ be true, and all other $p$ be false.

Let us recursively define $q$ such that for all $x, y$:
$$q(x, y) \Longleftrightarrow p(x, y) \vee \exists(t).(q(x, t) \wedge q(t, y))$$

Why is $q(c, a)$ consistent with the definitions of $p$ and $q$ above?

By the definition of $q$, $c$ must always be the first parameter to $p$, and $a$ must always be the second parameter to $p$. However, there is no such $p$ where this is true. $\neg\exists(y).(p(c, y)) \wedge \neg\exists(x).(p(x, a)).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some oddities with your presentation. I don't know what you mean by "such that $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ exist for all $x,y$". Either $p$ and $q$ are fully defined on their domains, or they are not binary relations in the logic.

Your "definition" of $q$ is also not recursive. While you can think of the equivalence as modeling a recursion, it's just a constraint. This leads to why I used scare quotes around "definition". This does not uniquely define $q$. The *minimal* relation satisfying that constraint would be the transitive closure of $p$ and would contain only $(a,b)$, $(b,c)$, and $(a,c)$. From this, you would be right. But there is nothing stating that $q$ is the minimal relation satisfying that constraint. If $\forall x,y.q(x,y)$ held, your equivalence would also hold. The constraint only states that $q$ *contains* the transitive closure of $p$, not that it *is* the transitive closure of $p$.

Comment: Thanks, Derek! Good points on "recursion" and constraints. I get that if $\forall x, y. q(x, y)$ held, the biconditional would still hold. I also get that the transitive closure of $p$ is a subset of the transitive closures of $q$. However, I still don't get why $q(c, a)$ is consistent with the constraints of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @KooZhengqun What is your definition of "consistent"?

Comment: There exists some truth assignment to relational constants $p(x,y), q(x,y)$ (at least $1$ of $2^{2*3^2}$ truth assignments) such that the biconditional relating $q(c, a)$ is true.

Comment: @KooZhengqun Then simply choose a truth assignment where $q(c,a)$ is true; none of your axioms disallow that. However, we would say then that $q(c,a)$ is [*satisfiable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Validity.2C_satisfiability.2C_and_logical_consequence), not that it is consistent. The term "consistency" is usually applied to the theory as a whole. On the other hand, $q(c,a)$ is not *valid* (see previous link) because it is not true for *all* truth assignments that make the axioms true.

Comment: Ah right, I meant to include the constraints of $p$ and $q$ in the definition of consistency. I don't get why my axioms allow $q(c, a$ though? My concern is in the last paragraph of my main question.

Comment: @KooZhengqun Are you parsing the constraint as $(q(x,y)\iff p(x,y))\lor\exists t.q(x,t)\land q(t,y)$ or as $q(x,y)\iff(p(x,y)\lor\exists t.q(x,t)\land q(t,y))$?

Comment: The latter. $\vee$ takes precedence over $\Longleftrightarrow$.

Comment: @KooZhengqun Okay, good. Then $q(c,a)\iff p(c,a)\lor\exists t.q(c,t)\land q(t,a)$. If $p(c,a)$ is false then this simplifies to $q(c,a)\iff\exists t.q(c,t)\land q(t,a)$. So $q(c,a)$ being true when $p(c,a)$ is false implies that $q$ must hold at other points besides those in the minimal model, e.g. $q(c,c)$. If it doesn't, then it is an illegal truth assignment. As I said before, if you have a truth assignment that makes $q(x,y)$ true for all $x$ and $y$ (including $q(c,a)$), then $q(x,y)\iff p(x,y)\lor\exists t.q(x,t)\land q(t,y)$ will be satisfied for any truth assignment for $p$.

Comment: Thank you so much Derek, I finally get it!